# How to implement multipart mixed api in python using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am trying to implement below API in python using requests but not sure how to upload 2 different files as a part of multi post

```
POST https://na.abc.net/api/v1/operations/systems/register
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="BoundaryUgix6QHMxLwJ4siU"
--BoundaryUgix6QHMxLwJ4siU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
// CSV attached
...
--BoundaryUgix6QHMxLwJ4siU
// JSON attached
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="defaultValues"; filename="defaultValues.json"
Content-Type: application/json
{
"defaultApplications" : ["45aa62ac003841fb8fb5b3b21cdf7f86","45aa62ac003841fb8fb5b3b21cdf7f87"],
"offerId" : "25aa92ac003841fb8fb5b3b21cdf7f17"
}

--BoundaryUgix6QHMxLwJ4siU--
```

API response in json format

Comment: `requests.post(url, files={...})` Check requests documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `files` parameter to `requests.post` for that. Check the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) for `files` parameter to `request.request` for more information.

For your case, it would be:

```py
import requests
resp = requests.post(
    'https://na.abc.net/api/v1/operations/systems/register',
    files={
        'file': ('file.csv', b'a,b,c\n1,2,3', 'text/csv'),
        'defaultValues': ('defaultValues.json', b'{"data":"file"}', 'application/json'),
    },
)
```

Replace the `b'a,b,c\n1,2,3'` and `b'{"data":"file"}'` with your file contents.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Oh... well at least I didn't use another library to solve it :-D Not like there are many better than `requests`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I edited my answer to make it clearer. Thanks for catching!